# Vue.js - How to display all property keys and nested property values?

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

Couldn't find a better title, my issue is hard to describe in one sentence. I'm trying to loop through an imported object generated by some third party package, but its structure is problematic:

```
obj: {
  "name1": {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
  },
  "name2": {
    "property1": "value3",
    "property2": "value4",
  },
  "name3": {
    "property1": "value5",
    "property2": "value6",
  }
}
```

I want to display not just `property1` and `property2` but also the name preceding these:

```
- name1
  value1
  value2

- name2
  value3
  value4

...
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, i) in obj" :key="index">
    {{ item.property1 }}
    <br>
    {{ item.property2 }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I display the name as well, given this object' odd structure?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1095zq2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `key` property in your `v-for` loop and render it :

```
 <li v-for="(item,key, i) in obj" :key="index">
     {{key}}
      <br>
     {{ item.property1 }}
      <br>
      {{ item.property2 }}
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the object key with `Object.keys()`, and display the object value from the key with another `v-for`

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in Object.keys(obj)" :key="index">
      {{ item }}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(property, key) in obj[item]" :key="property">
          {{ key }} -> {{ property }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```